# Some buttons have :focus style applied on click

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

Why do some buttons get :focus style applied when clicking them and some don't? For example, [angular-ui modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) close buttons have it applied, but try [W3Schools button element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test) and it doesn't.

EDIT: I am reopening this question. Forgive me, I had forgotten a bit about this, because I really tought that it was solved until yesterday I really tried it out. So I did something like this: `.btn:focus:not(:active) { outline: none;}`, but the problem is that then it also doesn't show focus when using `tab` button. And forget about bootstrap at all, it's not it!

It seems that the focus effect becomes visible on button click when it's `background-color` property for `:focus` is defferent from default. Maybe true for some other properties as well.

So - if the `background` is default, then you can see focus effect only when using `tab` key or setting it to `:focus` manually. If the `background` is different, you can see the effect also on click. Plunker demonstrating this: https://plnkr.co/edit/2eKrtwl2wZcj3Ty4JJSu?p=preview

Maybe I have answered my question myself, maybe not, don't know.

edit2: Just saw @musically_ut edit giving almost the same example.

**UPDATE**

After discussion with @Error404, I can clarify the question more precisely.
So the question is - why default `button`'s `outline`  style is not showing when it has been **clicked**?

See "clicked" in bold, because it is not working only on click. It works when focusing on it using keyboards `tab` key, it works when setting it manually with developer tools.

Mostly all answers so far argue that it loses or doesn't have focus at all when clicked, but it does. You can change `button`'s `background` or `border` and probably some other property too and suddenly, when you click it, you see the outline. Or you can change the `outline` itself to something else in `:focus` rule and it will show also.

Comment: What is exactly the new question?

Comment: @Error404 Question is still the same - "Why do some buttons get :focus style applied when clicking them and some don't?" It's hard for me to believe that it's actaully because of the background.

Comment: But I am still not secure about what you refer to. The `:focus` is only an event that detects that you have clicked on the button, nothing about changes on `CSS`. `CSS` gives to you the possibility to add some functionallity when this event is triggered. Of course, if you want to see some change when you click on the button you have to add some changes on `CSS` (to see the effect). It does not mind if it is the background, border, etc. Look at this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2AGHs57APZryoWQiqnS?p=preview) using border.

Comment: But something is different whether some of the button's default style properties have been changed or not. I mentioned `background` and now I see that `border` also applies. You see - you only added rule for `border`, but at the same time you can also see the default `outline` style applied. If you remove the `border` rule, then `outline` also disappears.

Comment: But the outline also appears if you do not set any property. See this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8jAvlgdPWHAUbud9Mrgn?p=preview) and let me know if it is what you are refering.

Comment: @Error404 wow. Stranger and stranger. And if you set the `background-color` to `buttonface` or `#ddd` as in @musically_ut example (value seems to be the same), the outline disappears.

Answer (score 2):

angular-ui is based on Bootstrap css framework that manage lot's of little things for style.

THe W3C example is only html without any kind of style applied.

Comment: I can't understand how this could be done in css, because both buttons actually have the same outline rule applied on focus, which you can see by manually setting their state to focus in chrome dev tools. But judging by this plunker it still has to do something with bootstrap https://plnkr.co/edit/1cAALd7XPXr1KgEASUjJ?p=preview

Comment: THe btn class in bootstrap manage the behavior .btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
} Hope this will help

Comment: This helps. Thanks. I will overwrite .btn:focus then, but leaving those with :active rule.

Answer (score 1):

angular-ui modal probably has additional CSS which creates the :focus selector behaviour, whereas W3 school doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`:focus` pseudo class follows the element which has [*focus* on the page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/). This can be a button, or an `input`, `textarea`, `<a>` link or any other element which can be `Tabbed` to (see: [tabindex attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)) or given focus otherwise (touching, mouse-clicks, etc.).

In the `angular-ui` example, nothing *steals* the focus away from the button after the click. However, on the W3-school, the focus is stolen by the alert box. Hence, the `<button>` loses the `:focus` pseudo class.

---

Curioser and curioser.

It seems that, on Chrome at least, the `background-color` CSS property on `button:focus` should be something other than `#ddd` for the button to keep focus after a click.

Demo: http://codepen.io/musically_ut/pen/eZjWeq

Comment: Then what does steal it away when there isn't alert box? I don't see it even flashing for a moment, which is 3rd behaviour which I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

After your comments, I think you are looking for the reason why a button with `background-color: #ddd;` does not have `outline`.

```css
button.buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

The main reason here I think, is that is not an `outline` what you are looking for because if you disable it on a `button` with a different `background-color`, the focus effect still appears.

```css
button.buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #dde;
  outline: none; /* I also proved with 0 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

It seems that it is a special border because if you set another border is the only way this *special border for focus* will disappear.

```css
button.buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #dde;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

I was curious about why this happens, maybe `#ddd` is the *default special border colour* was the main question I had on my mind. So let's know what border colour has.

```js
var buttontag = document.getElementById('buttontag');
buttontag.onfocus = function(){
  var border = window.getComputedStyle(buttontag).getPropertyValue("border");
  alert(border);
}

var border = window.getComputedStyle(buttontag).getPropertyValue("border");
alert(border);
```

```css
button {}
:focus {background-color: #ddd }
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

It does not matter if it is on focus or not, it will always has the colour `rgb(221, 221, 221)` on the border which equivalent is `#DDDDDD` on hexadecimal and that is the same as `#ddd`.

**We have it!:** The reason why it does not seems that this `button` is on focus when it has `background-color: #ddd;` is because it has the same `border colour` as `background-color` so it does not has any contrast between them (`background-color` and `border`).

**Remember:** `onfocus` event just detects when a `focus` event is triggered on a `button` (or other focusable element). It does not have reference with anything about `CSS`, it just gets the event, but does not have anything related with `CSS`. It can has default values that the browser sets on the focusable element, though.

Is the reason why if you change the `background-color` of the `button` it makes the effect as if you have clicked on the `button`, because both values are different and it makes contrast between them. If you set the same `background-color` you will never get the feel that the `button` is being clicked.

Comment: Yes, you were kind of correct about the question - "why a button with background-color: #ddd; does not have outline.", I got mixed up in my words between this and focus. But I don't understand with what you are going further in your answer, especially about border, which doesn't interest me. But the question would be more precise as - "why a button with ... doesn't have outline when clicking it", because it does have it when using tab key or setting it manually in chrome developer tools.

Comment: I was talking about the border because I thought that the `outline` line disappear to put a `border` (look at my example 2 in which I disable `outline` and the effect still comes) and if you had the same, of course it was impossible that you see any contrast (or effect) on the button. But you are right, there is an `outline` line that is in both cases, but in one of them does not appear (when background is `#ddd`).

Comment: Is this what did you want? It is a curious effect and I will look around it. I have created this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/fb6tLzgL/) to see that the button that has background `#ddd` also has an `outline` line. Also, I do not know what do you mean with _tab key_.

Comment: @John It is also funny that if you assign to the button that has the `background-color: #ddd` the same `outline` that it has at the moment it is going to be shown when you do not have the focus on it. See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/fb6tLzgL/1/). I also could find on the [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#propdef-outline) that _'Invert' is expected to perform a color inversion on the pixels on the screen. This is a common trick to ensure the focus border is visible, regardless of color background._ so it seems to be problems with some backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, nice demonstrating that the outline is actaully there, but I think that you are still away from my point. Outline can be seen when using `tab` key, just click anywhere in the plunker preview page and hit `tab` on your keyboard, it will focus on the button and you will see the outline, but you won't see it when clicking the button.

Comment: @John Oh, now I notice what you mean before with _tab key_ (sorry). It is a very strange effect and I am very curious now about why it happens. I will try to get it out or get an explanation of what is happening there. Is like the first button (with `background: #ddd`) has the outline but do not display it. Very strange.

Comment: @John I have tried to inspect the element and it has the outline all the time. It has the same properties that the other button (with `background: #dde`) so it seems to be a bug (I will post a question about it if it is ok for you). You can reproduce the effect both for tab key and clicking on the button, though. See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0wj0z0xb/) and let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: But that is `box-shadow` what you are seeing, not `outline`

Comment: @John Yes, I know. It is a workaround that I make to get a similar effect when you focus on a default button. If you try to set the default `outline`, it will never work. See this another [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0wj0z0xb/1/). It is why I said that it seems a bug, and if it is ok for you I will post a question about it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Yes, you could open question.

Answer (score 0):

:focus is a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp), which is used by tools like jQuery to trigger events, apply CSS styles, etc. Looking at the examples you provided, I do not see an explicit set of :focus. When a button is clicked, jQuery will interpret the button as :focus. a vanilla HTML button will not have this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with All my AngularJs app, I usually remove the focus from buttons when they are clicked, I know this is a hack but it works :D.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show focus outline use below piece of code,

```html
<button type="button" tabindex="-1">Click Me!</button>
```

***OR***

```css
 :focus {outline:none;}
```

And if you want to outline on focus then use below piece of code,

```
 :focus {outline: 1px solid #5B9DD9}
```

Other styles(like background or border etc.) you can use as you want to.
I hope this will help, if you have doubt then let me know.

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

What I noticed when inspecting the button through Inspect Element and triggering a :focus, the button gets the style

```css
:focus { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px; }
```

[image]

This does not create an outline on the button, though.

After debugging and reading some pages on internet i come to know that the focus on button only shows up with a keyboard press, because in the beginning it was necessary to show what element is focused on while now with a mouse it's clear what is being focused on, since you are actively moving the mouse to the button

Comment: Yes you are right on click also button has focus, But that outline is not visible.

Comment: What I noticed when inspecting the button through Inspect Element and triggering a :focus, the button gets the style 
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
This does not create an outline on the button, though.

After debugging and reading some pages on internet i come to know that the focus on button only shows up with a keyboard press, because in the beginning it was necessary to show what element is focused on while now with a mouse it's clear what is being focused on, since you are actively moving the mouse to the button.

Comment: I don't think that you have set it to `:focus`. Your checkbox is empty. But strange that the style is visible. It works for me and some other, who have replied here.

Comment: i have button not check box, and that style is only visible if button is in focus.

Comment: I am talking about checkbox for `:focus` pseido class in style editor on the right side

Comment: the checkbox is independent of click or tab focus, will not get checked on button focus, that checkbox is for a developer who wants to test using a dev tool.  If you click on that checkbox  you will see button is in focus.

Comment: Ah, I tought that by this - "What I noticed when inspecting the button through Inspect Element and triggering a :focus", you meant that you triggered it manually. Anyway - it's what I'v been saying all along. And your last paragraph doesn't make sense, because you will see outline on click if some of button's styles have been changed. Everything I'v said before...